# How to save file in existing database?

Tags: sql-server, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model for my database from SQL Server 2016, and I don't find my viewmodel as you written to edit the file type to `HttpPostedFileBase`, so what should I do?

This is my model, view and controller

**Model**

```
public partial class HMW_Solution
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HMW_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Student_ID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public byte[] Sol_File { get; set; }

    public virtual HMW HMW { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<h2>AddAnswer</h2>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>HMW_Solution</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <input type="hidden" name="HMW_ID" value=@ViewBag.HMW_ID>
    <input type="hidden" name="Student_ID" value=@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StudentID"]>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @{
        Byte[] file;


     }
    <input type="file" name="Sol_File" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAnswer([Bind(Include = "HMW_ID,Student_ID,Answer,Sol_File")]HMW_Solution s, HttpPostedFileBase Sol_File)
{
     //byte[] bytes = s.Sol_File.ToArray();
     //HttpPostedFileBase file = s.Sol_File;

     //byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[s.Sol_File.Length];
     //s.Sol_File.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);

     //using (Stream inputStream = Sol_File.InputStream)
     //{
     //    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
     //    if (memoryStream == null)
     //    {
     //        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     //        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
     //    }
     //    s.Sol_File = memoryStream.ToArray();
     //}

     if (Sol_File.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Sol_File.FileName);
         var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), guid + fileName);

         Sol_File.SaveAs(path);

         string fl = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
         string[] split = fl.Split('\\');
         string newpath = split[1];
         string imagepath = "~/uploads/" + newpath;
         upload.length = imagepath;

         db.FileUploads.Add(upload);
         db.SaveChanges();
     }

     db.HMW_Solution.Add(s);
     db.SaveChanges();

     return RedirectToAction("showHMW", "HMW", new { Cource_ID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CourseID"] });
}
```